# What is the meaning of "res" in C++?

Tags: c++

I've tried Googling and actually searching this website for a concise answer on this and so far I have been unable to find some help, I believe it might be because the answer is too simple.

I have just started uni and we have some exercises to resolve. In one of them I am presented with the following:

```
float avge(int a, int b, int c) {
  float res;
  res = (a + b + c) / 3.0;
  return res;
}

int main() {
  int n1, n2, n3;
  float m;
  cin >> n1;
  cin >> n2;
  cin >> n3;
  m = avge(n1, n2, n3);
  cout << m << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

It works as intended but I can't understand what `res` does for the code. Could someone explain it to me?

Comment: its the name of a variable (presumably short for `result`), you could change it to `foo` and your program would still work in the same way

Comment: 1) It is a variable declared in a statement `float res;` What exactly, about it, is unclear for you? 2) This should be explained in the lectures, in your university. Alternatively, you can learn from one of [these C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Ignore this if it seems confusing. In general, try to initialize variables when they are created, rather than create them and initialize them later. This code (not yours, I know, just giving unsolicited advice) should be `float res = (a + b + c) / 3.0;` instead of `float res; res = (a + b + c) / 3.0;`. It's not wrong as written, but it's a bad habit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`res` is the name of a local variable in the function `avge` that is returned at then end of that function.

```
// Variable of type float with name "res" is declared
float res;

// Compute some value and assign it to this variable
res = (a+b+c)/3.0;

// Return the variable to the caller
return res;
```

"res" usually is an abbreviation for "result".

Comment: Thank you that makes sense. These are exercises in preparation for the class in which this will be explained and I was simply trying to make sense of it.